# Broken logout link in chat mobile theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, logout

I tried to logout from SE via the logout button on the mobile chat interface:

> [image]

However, the link points to https://chat.stackexchange.com/logout which gives Page Not Found.

In full site theme, the logout link in chat top bar is correct, pointing to https://stackexchange.com/users/logout as it should.

Comment: There is no such thing "log out from chat". It's the same logout from all SE sites

Comment: I should have caught that. Edited. :)

Comment: Got it and edited to reflect actual bug, all the rest wasn't really relevant. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. I was like "I have no idea what is relevant here!" so I kinda infodumped. Thanks for making it a lot clearer.

Comment: @Adam no answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's literally nothing to say. It's fixed. It's done. The tag says it all.

Comment: @Adam hundreds of "This was fixed/Fix was pushed/will be fixed in rev X/etc" says otherwise but guess it's indeed not that vital. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: I don't get the "page not found" error, but I'm not logged out either.